# Query core data store based on a transient calculated value

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm fairly new to the more complex parts of Core Data.

My application has a core data store with 15K rows. There is a single entity.

I need to display a subset of those rows in a table view filtered on a calculated search criteria, and for each row displayed add a value that I calculate in real time but don't store in the entity.

The calculation needs to use a couple of values supplied by the user.

A hypothetical example:

Entity: contains fields "id", "first", and "second"

User inputs: 10 and 20

Search / Filter Criteria: only display records where the entity field "id" is a prime number between the two supplied numbers. (I need to build some sort of complex predicate method here I assume?)

Display: all fields of all records that meet the criteria, along with a derived field (not in the the core data entity) that is the sum of the "id" field and a random number, so each row in the tableview would contain 4 fields:

"id", "first", "second", -calculated value-

From my reading / Googling it seems that a transient property might be the way to go, but I can't work out how to do this given that the search criteria and the resultant property need to calculate based on user input.

Could anyone give me any pointers that will help me implement this code? I'm pretty lost right now, and the examples I can find in books etc. don't match my particular needs well enough for me to adapt them as far as I can tell.

Thanks

Darren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to stop thinking in terms of fields, rows and columns as none of those structures are actually part of Core Data. In this case, it is important because Core Data supports arbitrarily complex fetches but the sqlite store does not. So, if you use a sqlite store your fetches are restricted those supported by SQLite.

In this case, predicates aimed at SQLite can't perform complex operations such as calculating whether an attribute value is prime.

The best solution for your first case would be to add a boolean attribute of `isPrime` and then modify the setter for your `id` attribute to calculate whether the set id value is prime or not and then set the `isPrime` accordingly. That will be store in the SQLite store and can be fetched against e.g. `isPrime==YES &&((first<=%@) && (second>=%@))`

The second case would simply use a transient property for which you would supply a custom getter to calculate its value when the managed object was in memory.

One often overlooked option is to not use an sqlite store but to use an XML store instead. If the amount of data is relatively small e.g. a few thousand text attributes with a total memory footprint of a few dozen meg, then an XML store will be super fast and can handle more complex operations.

SQLite is sort of the stunted stepchild in Core Data. It's is useful for large data sets and low memory but with memory becoming ever more plentiful, its loosing its edge. I find myself using it less these days. You should consider whether you need sqlite in this particular case.